# iOS Provisioning profile: Valid signing identity not found

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to test the push notification functionality on a device. I followed this article. http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

So the issue is when I download the development provisioning profile and import it into xcode then it says the valid code signing identity is not found.

[image: organiser says: code signing identity is not found]
This stops me from building the app as General projects settings says no matching provisioning profiles found.

[image: General projects settings says no matching provisioning profiles found]

No matter how many times I push fix button this wont go.

The app ID and provisioning profiles looks good on iOS Dev center.

[image: App ID settings]
[image: Development Provisioning profile settings]

I have tried deleting them and recreating them again and again but issue remains the same.

Also my build settings are:
[image: App Build settings]

There is only one option for code signing identity and that is "iPhone Developer" as no other matching code signing identity is found. I have tried deleting the app and recreating it in xcode also. I have double checked the bundle ID. And I have google a lot. Everyone says revoking the certificate and recreating fixed the issue but not in my case.

Also the keychain seems to have the correct public and private key.
[image: Keychain access]

I am stuck on it for last 2 days :(

Comment: did u create the .cer from your system's keychain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by deleting all development certificates in iOS dev centre (even my iOS development certificate) and recreating new ones from beginning. I had 2 iOS development certificates and I think Xcode was confused about which to use. This happened because I have revoked my development certificate from another machine and thus creating a new one. Somehow it ended up in two developer certificates managed by xcode. Since then i have'n tested any app on device and so though that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to delete the old .cer file from you Keychain and download the latest one.

If the **CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest** is created from another machine, get the corresponding **.p12** file and add it to your Keychain.

Thats it. Now double click on your provisioning profile and it should be valid.

Worst solution:

If you are unable to get the .p12 file, Revoke your existing certificate and configure all again.

Comment: how to add p12 file to keychain? double clicking it?

Comment: did u create the .cer from your system's keychain? or some created it for you?

Comment: everything was created on my system

Comment: then a delete and add again will work fine. Also just clean your Xcode project.

Comment: currently the ios dev center is down, will retry and let you know here

Answer (score -1):

Install the valid p12 file (i.e) double click the valid p12 file.